# Select Top Level Domain from email address in Hive

Tags: regex, hive, hiveql

I'm trying to find the length of the top level domains within an emailaddress column.

I've tried a few iterations of regexp_replace, but no success.

Failed attempts are all around the following command:

```
length(regexp_replace(emailaddress,'@\.(.*)',1)) --counts before '@' characters
```

Intended Output:

```
emailaddress = asdfasdf@gmail.com
length = 3
emailaddress = asdfasdf@gmail.co
length = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use

```
length(regexp_extract(emailaddress,'[.]([^.]+)$', 1))
```

The `[.]([^.]+)$` regex will match a dot and then will capture 1 or more chars other than a dot up to the end of the input. The `1` argument will make `regexp_extract`  function return just the substring captured in Group 1, and `length` will return the length of that value.

In case you may have emails with no dot in the host part, you may restrict the pattern even further (to disallow matching `@` in the negated character class):

```
length(regexp_extract(emailaddress,'[.]([^@.]+)$', 1))
```

Comment: I don't think this works - I tried both but they're returning looks like the full length of the email minus 1

Comment: @max You must use `regexp_extract`, not `regexp_replace`

Answer (score 0):

One more method. Use `reverse`, `split` by `'.'`, take first array element, calculate length:

```
select length(split(reverse(emailaddress),'\\.')[0]);
```

Also `regexp_extract` works fine. Testing these two methods:

```
with data as (
select stack (2,
              'asdfasdf@gmail.com',
              'asdfasdf@gmail.co'
             ) as emailaddress
)

select emailaddress, 
       length(split(reverse(emailaddress),'\\.')[0])      length_method_1, 
       length(regexp_extract(emailaddress, '\\.(.+)$',1)) length_method_2 
  from data;
```

Result:

```
OK
emailaddress    length_method_1 length_method_2
asdfasdf@gmail.com      3       3
asdfasdf@gmail.co       2       2
Time taken: 6.253 seconds, Fetched: 2 row(s)
```